# How to process websocket data in a non-blocking manner?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, websocket

How to process websocket data in a non-blocking manner?

The below example shows that when `ws.recv()` is called and nothing is received, `ws.recv()` blocks the rest of the code from running:

```
from websocket import create_connection
url = 'ws://example.com'
ws = create_connection(url)

ws.recv()  # blocks
```

How to implement something along the lines of (without blocking):

```
from websocket import create_connection
url = 'ws://example.com'
ws = create_connection(url)

# non-blocking
if ws.not_empty():
    ws.recv()
```

How to process websocket data in a non-blocking manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using Python >= 3.5 is an option, you might want to check out `asyncio` which allows you to write single-threaded, yet concurrent code. This is typically useful for handling i/o bound code such as networking.

Be aware there is a bit of a learning curve if its your first time using `asyncio`.

Once you've familiarized yourself with the basics, there is an excellent `websockets` module which leverages `asyncio`:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websockets